# Unmatch Selected Index in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview, this gridview has a select button, and a row for search below the header. When i click the select button, they go to right row. 
[image]
But, when i click the last row on this page, they dont bring me to the details of that row. The gridview 'select' button will move one row upright. Like this [image]

Whats wrong, i dont have any idea.

```
 protected void gv_rdk_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = gv_rdk.SelectedRow;

            if (row.RowIndex >= gv_rdk.Rows.Count-2) { return; }

            GridViewRow selectedRow = gv_rdk.Rows[row.RowIndex +1];

            string nond, nost, halst;

            nond = selectedRow.Cells[0].Text;
            Session["nomornd"] = nond;
            nost = selectedRow.Cells[1].Text;
            Session["nomorst"] = nost;
            halst = selectedRow.Cells[2].Text;
            Session["perihalst"] = halst;
            Response.Redirect("rdk_rincian.aspx");
        }
```

and this is the gridview code

```
 <asp:GridView ID="gv_rdk"
    CssClass="table table-bordered"
    runat="server"
    BorderColor="#1E6BBC"
    BorderStyle="None"
    OnDataBound="OnDataBound"
    BorderWidth="1px"
    CellPadding="3"
    ShowFooter="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    AllowPaging="True"
    OnSelectedIndexChanged="gv_rdk_SelectedIndexChanged"
    OnPageIndexChanging="OnPaging" DataSourceID="ds_rdk">
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFEFEF" />
    <PagerStyle CssClass="gridview" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="white" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="nond" HeaderText="Nomor ND" SortExpression="nond" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="nost" HeaderText="Nomor Surat Tugas" SortExpression="nost" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="halst" HeaderText="Hal Surat Tugas" SortExpression="halst" />
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" ControlStyle-CssClass="btn btn-success" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ds_rdk" runat="server" SelectMethod="AmbilData" TypeName="quittance.Kelas.rdkDataAccessLayer"></asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Javascript for search textbox:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('.tabelst').each(function (i) {
                $(this).quicksearch("[id*=gv_rdk] tr:not(:has(th))", {
                    'testQuery': function (query, txt, row) {
                        return $(row).children(":eq(" + i + ")").text().toLowerCase().indexOf(query[0].toLowerCase()) != -1;
                    }
                });
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: Why `GridViewRow selectedRow = gv_rdk.Rows[row.RowIndex +1];` and not `gv_rdk.Rows[row.RowIndex];` ?

Comment: Because there is a row containing textbox for search, so i add up 1? Isnt it right? or Did i miss something?

Comment: where and how have you added this row? Why don't you use the `TemplateField.HeaderTemplate` to add this search-box?

Comment: I made it using javascript, so that the user can search the gridview interactively without refreshing the page.

Comment: If you've created it with javascript it doesn't exist in the page's control-collection. So you don't need to use `row.RowIndex +1` but `row.RowIndex`. It just exists in the client-html.

Comment: Oke, thank you very much. But do you know why the select button move one row up, and how to improve this, please see the picture. I click on the buttom row of gridview, it doesnt go to detail even i have change gv_rdk.Rows[row.RowIndex]

Comment: You may have a conflict with the Paging index